# raise BuilderException when use Builder.load_file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

1. When I run main.py file without:

```
Builder.load_file('mycoolapp.kv')
```

Simply like this:

```
class MyCoolApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
```

Everything works perfectly.

2. But when I add

```
Builder.load_file('mycoolapp.kv')
```

I have issues because my .kv file has self.:

```
<MyRoundedButton_push@Button>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    back_color: (0, 1, 1, 1)
    pressed_color: (0, 1, 1, 1)
    border_radius: [10]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: self.back_color if self.state == 'normal' else self.pressed_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

How can I handle this mistake?

```
raise BuilderException(

BuilderException: Parser: File "...mycoolapp.kv", line 804:
...
    802:    canvas.before:
    803:        Color:
>>  804:            rgb: self.back_color if self.state == 'normal' else self.pressed_color
    805:        RoundedRectangle:
    806:            size: self.size
...
IndexError: list index out of range
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/l5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 925, in _build_canvas
    setattr(instr, key, value)
  File "kivy/graphics/context_instructions.pyx", line 286, in kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Color.rgb.__set__
```

It happened because I tried to add ScreenManager and use multiple screens.

--------------- UPDATE ---------------

My .py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kivy.require('1.9.0')


class MyGameScreen(BoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGameScreen, self).__init__()
        self.i = 0
        
    def btn_push_press(self):
        if self.i == 0:
            self.btn_push.back_color = (0, 0, 1, 1)
            self.btn_push.pressed_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
            self.i = 1
        elif self.i == 1:
            self.btn_push.back_color = (0, 1, 1, 1)
            self.btn_push.pressed_color = (1, 0, 1, 1)
            self.i = 0

# Builder.load_file('mycoolapp.kv')

class MyCoolApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGameScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyCoolApp().run()
```

My .kv file:

```
<MyGameScreen>:  
    btn_push: btn_push
    
    BoxLayout:
        id: game_screen
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        MyRoundedButton_push:
            id: btn_push
            text: "PUSH"
            font_size: 48
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            on_press: root.btn_push_press()

                
<MyRoundedButton_push@Button>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    back_color: (0, 1, 1, 1)
    pressed_color: (1, 0, 1, 1)
    border_radius: [100]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: self.back_color if self.state == 'normal' else self.pressed_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

Everything works until I uncomment Builder.load_file('mycoolapp.kv')

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I added what you asked me to the question after: --------------- UPDATE ---------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `kv` file is being loaded twice when you uncomment the `Builder.load_file('mycoolapp.kv')` line. Although the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv) would lead you to believe that your `kv` file will not be automatically loaded, it is actually loaded automatically. The fix is to simply not uncomment that line, or change the name of your `kv` file.